# What is this song from Episode 53 of Hunter x Hunter?

Tags: music, hunter-x-hunter

I want to find the music from Episode 53 (Yorknew City arc) starting at 6:51

It's an Asian-style song with what sounds like a Japanese musical instrument called a shamisen.

Comment: Do you mean the 2011 HxH series or the 1999 one?  I checked [episode 53](http://www.crunchyroll.com/hunter-x-hunter/episode-53-fake-x-and-x-psyche-611493) of 2011, and the music playing at 6:51 is a choral.  It began at 6:30.  I can't make out a shamisen, either.  I do not have access to the 1999 version.  Please either verify that the choral is the song you mean, or edit your post with correct information.

Comment: I meant 2011 Hxh series

Comment: Okay... In that case I do not know what it is.  Except I don't think it's Asian and I don't hear a shamisen.  It's more along the lines of a European Gregorian chant, although not all male and not acapella.  I like it, though.

Answer (score 2):

As RichF said, the song of episode 53, at 6:51 doesn't sound asian-style at all, but if that is the song that you want, it's called Dirge From The Dark Side.

Comment: To be more precise, it's when Kuroro speaks to Kortopi in the amphitheatre,(destroyed by the fight between Zoldyck vs Kuroro, but the music can be heard when it's finished)

No problem if you don't find it ^^ and thanks for the music that you found, even if it's not the music I'm looking for.

Answer (score 2):

I was not able to find that particular piece of music in any of the OST volumes. The song in question seems to last less than a minute so they might have decided to not name/list it. Here are two different lists of all of the music in HxH feel free to browse them I could have missed it.

**[Hunter x Hunter Wikia - Music](http://hunterxhunter.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_Hunter_%C3%97_Hunter_Music)** **this link also contains music information about the 1999 airing of HxH

**[reddit/r/HunterxHunter - Comprehensive Hunter x Hunter 2011 Music List](https://www.reddit.com/r/HunterXHunter/comments/3e80hw/comprehensive_hunter_x_hunter_2011_music_list/)**